# How can I use handler as a timer to switch between images using animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-handler

I have already created the code using handler and runnable so it executes each X milliseconds,  however if I use animation, the handler postDelayed seems to go crazy and the screen starts blinking with the images being set every second.

Do you know any problems on using handler as timer when using animation between transitions?

Here is a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/julianonunes/6187324b5b965683d1bb) with the code.

Comment: you should REALLY follow java standards.. member varialbles should ALWAYS start with an 'm' like so: mVariableName , this is so we can tell them apart from your local method variables at first glance.

Comment: @JoxTraex I don't have much background in Java and for each Android sample code I see a different coding "standard". But I like your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using setDelay(), setRepeatCount (possible use of Animation.INFINITE), and at the end of animation switch image (add AnimationListener then) ?

Comment: Every 10 seconds a ImageView should Fade out, load a different Image and Fade in. How can I achieve this using your suggestion? Do you have an example?